# AC fan and Compressor not cycling properly and turning off

Tags: air-conditioning

AC was not cooling and out side unit fan was turing on intermittently, install the new capicitor, problem stays same, fan and compressor ran, fan stop befor ecompressor, compressor run little longer without fan then stop. Change the fan motor, still not working. It runs intermittently. Something may be getting heat up and stop running, but what?

Comment: The motor appears to be overheating

Comment: With a new motor the problem may be in the control board. Or a check of the inside evaporator freezing. Some units with low air flow and or low freon charge shut down. I have only found 1 unit (dirty filters) caused the compressor shutdown. Low freon causes the evaporator to freeze and the compressor to over heat then shut down until the compressor motor is cool and restarts the fan on some units is turned on/off for 3/4 different reasons. If a full charge and no ice on the evaporator it could be the control board.

Comment: What's the make and model of the unit?

Comment: Must be a lot of perfectly good capacitors that get swapped out at random...